# Difference between @component tags x

Tags: angular

I am learning angular2 and i am lost at a point where the version i installed using angular cli and did ng generate component abc has @component which has ending templateUrl , styleUrl. But the version i downloaded from angular.io has template , style and vice versa. What is the difference between both?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html)? For example: *"**template** - inline-defined template for the view. **templateUrl** - url to an external file containing a template for the view"*. RTFM!

Answer (score 2):

- `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` point to *external* html and css files
- `template` and `styles` are used to define template and styles *inline*